# JavaScript SyntaxError in php print

Tags: javascript, php

I'm getting this error in java console: "SyntaxError: unterminated regular expression literal"

I really don't understand it. Below is my code, if someone could point out what am I missing I would be forever gratefull.

PHP Code:

```
print '
<script type="text/javascript">
function fakeUpload() {
    $("#fakeupload").val(this.files && this.files.length ? this.files[0].name : this.value.replace(/^C:\\fakepath\\/i, ""));
}
</script>';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two slashes (`\\`) become one slash in the output of PHP (`\`). You have to write four slashes (`\\\\`).

Let's see the output of your **current code**:

```
this.value.replace(/^C:\fakepath\/i, "");
```

The last backslash escapes the Regex terminator (the forward slash), therefore the regular expression terminal is unterminated.

Here is the output of the **updated code**:

```
this.value.replace(/^C:\\fakepath\\/i, "");
---------------------------------^^
escapes                           |
----------------------------------|
```

The last backslash won't affect anything because it is escaped by the backslash before it.

Answer (score 1):

You missed an escape slash here

```
this.value.replace(/^C:\\fakepath\\//i, ""));
                                    ^
```

Try like this

```
<?php
print '
<script type="text/javascript">
function fakeUpload() {
    $("#fakeupload").val(this.files && this.files.length ? this.files[0].name : this.value.replace(/^C:\\fakepath\\//i, ""));
}
</script>';
```